# Obtaining plain test from website - Invoke-WebRequest in PS 2.0

Tags: powershell

I have a URL that provides me information on the browser like this:

[image]

I need PS script that is able to list this values (always one column) and be able to put in on a file.

I can handle the file writing part of the work, but I haven't a clue on how to get the script read those values.

When I do "view page source" on the webpage I just get that plain text - no other information at all.

I've tried this:

```
$url = "http://..."
$result = Invoke-WebRequest $url
$elements = $result.AllElements | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty innerText 

$resultArray = @()

foreach($element in $elements.Split("`n")){
    {$resultArray += $element}

    Write-Output "$element"

}
```

But I get:

> The term 'Invoke-WebRequest' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Any chances to get this done using Powershell 2.0 (although I'm still not sure if that "`n" will work in this case)

Any hint please?

Comment: Is this PowerShell 2.0 ?

Comment: Which powershell version are you using?
`Invoke-WebRequest` wasnt added until version 3 I believe.

Comment: `($psversiontable.psversion).tostring()` will tell us what PS Version.

Comment: Yes I'm using PS 2.0, so my question is, how can I get my job done with 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use web client in old powershell.

```
$wc = new-object System.Net.WebClient

$text = $wc.DownloadString('http://websiteUrl')
```